# Correct syntax to read the value of a JSON string inside nested object using TJSONDataObject

Tags: json, delphi-2009

Can someone please help me with the correct syntax to access a string inside a nested object using JSONDataObjects from Andreas Hausladen

I have a JSON string returned from an API that contains an array of customers followed by a cursor pagination object (meta) eg

```
  {
  "customers": [
    {
      "id": "CU000DWEQWMRN4",
      "email": "theemail@outlook.com",
      "metadata": {
                         "member_name": "BLOGGS jim",
                         "membership_id": "4088"
                       }
    },
    {
      "id": "CU000DVEKR579S",
      "email": "anotheremail@outlook.com",
      "metadata": {
                        "membership_id": "5647"
                         }
    }
  ],
  "meta": {
              "cursors": {
                             "before": null,
                             "after": "ID456"
                             },
                  "limit": 50
               }
}
```

I an trying to get the values of `before` and `after` inside the `meta` object at the end

**What I have  tried**

```
var  Obj: TJsonObject;
       AfterID : string;
  
  begin
  Obj := TJsonObject.Parse(theJSON) as TJsonObject;
  AfterID :=    Obj['meta']['cursors']['after']  ;
```

**Problem**
I get the error message cannot convert object to string

**I also tried**

```
  var  
     Obj: TJsonObject;
     AfterID : string;
   begin   
   obj :=  Obj['meta'];
   Obj := Obj['cursors'];
   AfterID := Obj['after'];
```

**Problem**
I get the error message cannot convert object to string

I've also tried many other combinations of syntax but I won't clutter the question with all of those!

I am puzzled as I my syntax is correct when doing the same thing with a slightly different JSON retuned from another API that has a simpler cursor pagination structure eg

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "event": "accepted",
      "id": "G3wOhh",
      "user-variables": {},
      "log-level": "info",
      "method": "smtp"
    },
    {
      "event": "accepted",
      "id": "KLT56",
      "user-variables": {},
      "log-level": "info",
      "method": "smtp"
    }
  ],
  "paging": {
    "previous": "line 4",
    "first": "line 1",
    "last": "line 12",
    "next": "line 6"
  }
}
```

with this JSON, using

```
var
      Obj : TJsonObject;
      nextID : string;
begin
 Obj := TJsonObject.Parse(TheReturnedJSON) as TJDOJsonObject; 
 nextID := Obj['paging']['next'];
```

I get the correct value returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TJsonObject`'s default `[]` property is its `Values[]` property, which returns a `TJsonDataValueHelper`:

```pascal
property Values[const Name: string]: TJsonDataValueHelper read GetValue write SetValue; default;
```

So, reading `Obj['cursors']` returns a `TJsonDataValueHelper`, not a `TJsonObject`.

`TJsonDataValueHelper`'s default `[]` property is its `O[]` property, which returns a `TJsonDataValueHelper` representing a JSON object, not a JSON string:

```pascal
property O[const Name: string]: TJsonDataValueHelper read {$IFDEF BCB}GetObj{$ELSE}GetObject{$ENDIF} write SetObject; default;
```

`TJsonDataValueHelper` has an `S[]` property to read a string value:

```pascal
property S[const Name: string]: string read GetObjectString write SetObjectString;        // returns '' if property doesn't exist, auto type-cast except for array/object
```

So, try this instead:

```
AfterID := Obj['meta']['cursors'].S['after'];
```

```pascal
nextID := Obj['paging'].S['next'];
```

Alternatively, don't use `TJsonDataValueHelper` at all.  `TJsonObject` has an `O[]` property that returns a `TJsonObject`, and an `S[]` property for reading a string:

```pascal
property S[const Name: string]: string read GetString write SetString;        // returns '' if property doesn't exist, auto type-cast except for array/object
...
property O[const Name: string]: TJsonObject read {$IFDEF BCB}GetObj{$ELSE}GetObject{$ENDIF} write SetObject;   // auto creates object on first access
```

For example:

```
AfterID := Obj.O['meta'].O['cursors'].S['after'];
```

```pascal
nextID := Obj.O['paging'].S['next'];
```

Comment: Ok, Thank you. I have marked this as correct but can I ask where you found this out? The only 'documentation' I can find, here, https://github.com/ahausladen/JsonDataObjects is very brief, makes no mention of the .O or .S and only has a very simple example. Is there better documentation somewhere?

Comment: @user2834566 I got this information by simply looking at the JSONDataObject's source code itself.

Comment: Ah OK, that's what I've been trying to do as well but its a bit of a shame such a useful class doesn't have documented somewhere at least a sentence saying what properties and methods do what, or even a quick comment against each one in the source. I spent two or three days off and on trying to work out how to use this class before finally posting here in trepidation of getting shot down by certain other SO users. Not including you Remy, I'm very grateful for your help

Answer (score 1):

Incidentally, I'll add to Remy's answer to say that since the value of `'before'` in my sample JSON was `null`, I found I had to use the following code to avoid getting another typecast error when reading that value as `Obj.Values['meta'].O['cursors'].S['before'];`

```
var
  temp : variant;
  BeforeID : string;
begin
  //read the value into a variant by using .V just in case it's null. 
  //if it is then reading a string using .S gives an error
  temp := Obj.Values['meta'].O['cursors'].V['before']; 
  if not VarIsNull(temp) then  // it's not a null so we can convert to a string
    BeforeID := VarToStr(temp)
  else                         // it is null so assign whatever string is appropriate  
    BeforeID := '';
```

But using `.V` was just a guess. I'd love to know where all this is documented!

Comment: FYI, `VarToStr()` handles nulls to return a blank string, so you don't need the `VarIsNull()` check. But I would avoid using `Variant` when possible. `TJsonDataValueHelper` has a `Typ` property to tell you whether a value is a string vs a null vs ..., etc, as well as an `IsNull` method. Though I'm not sure the best way to get a `TJsonDataValueHelper` for a non-object/array.

Comment: I would probably just say to not use `TJsonDataValueHelper` at all, use `TJsonObject` as-is instead, which also has `IsNull`, eg: `var cursors: TJsonObject; BeforeID : string; begin cursors := Obj.O['meta'].O['cursors']; if not cursors.IsNull('before') then BeforeID := cursors.S['before'];` Or, I think `TJsonObject.S[]` handles `null` for you: `BeforeID := Obj.O['meta'].O['cursors'].S['before'];`

Comment: You are right, this is a bit confusing without proper documentation!

Comment: Brilliant, thank you Remy. All that information goes a long way to writing some sensible and readable code using this class. (Must admit though, rather shamefaced, that quite a big front end to a remote database that I've written for my mountaineering association has documentation that is a year or two out of date! One day I'll get around to doing the documentation instead of the development but whilst it's still just me doing the programming its more fun creating than documenting)  .

Comment: just for anyone else reading this. Remy you are correct that `cursors := Obj.O['meta'].O['cursors']; if not cursors.IsNull('before') then...` does work OK but Obj.O['meta'].O['cursors'].S['before']` doesn't seem to handle nulls. I'd hoped it would return an empty string but it just gives a conversion error.  Never mind, the ` if not cursors.IsNull()` construct is very handy though.